# The number of subtraction step in binary GCD algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

[Binary GCD algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Algorithm) is a algorithm which find a GCD of two positive integers. The algorithm proceeds recursively using the following reduction:
$$(a,b)=\begin{cases}
a&\text{if }a=b\\ 2(a/2,b/2)&\text{if $a$ and $b$ are even}\\
(a/2,b)&\text{if $a$ is even and $b$ is odd}\\
(a-b,b)&\text{if $a$, $b$ are odd, where }a>b\\
\end{cases}$$

It find a GCD by using division by 2 and subtraction.

My question is: it is known that the algorithm uses a subtraction at most $1+\log_2\max\{a,b\}$ times. *How to prove that inequality?* I don't know how to start it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: If you use the fourth step, your next step is very likely to be the third step.

Comment: This is not a **complete algorithm**! You get stuck e.g. with $\gcd(5,3)$:

$(5,3) \rightarrow (2,3) \rightarrow (1,3) \rightarrow ???$

You missed two important cases from the Wiki algorithm $\gcd(0,b)$ and the case
$a,b$ odd and $a<b$

Comment: @gammatester It is not a big problem, since $(1,3)=(3,1)$. We can change the order of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @tetori: Sure, but it should be included in an algorithm.

Comment: @vadim123 Yes, I know that point. But I struck on to write a detail of the proof. If $a$ and $b$ are odd and $(a-b,b)$ is reduced to $(a_1,b_1)$, $a_1>b_1$ by dividing by 2, then $\max((a-b)/2,b)\ge a_1$. But I don't know how to proceed it... Could you give more hints?